# how can convert a lunar datetime to datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have DateTime on a lunar calendar like this: 2018-08-02, I need to convert it to DateTime on the calendar.

Expect result after convert to DateTime like this: 2018-08-31

How can I do it by javascript or jquery?

Comment: Check the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-lunar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the comment you can check https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-lunar

Code example:

```js
const lunarDate = moment('2018-08-31').lunar();
const solarDate = lunarDate.solar().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(solarDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment-lunar@0.0.4/moment-lunar.min.js"></script>
```